# Refactoring the prop logic into a different component

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a `BaseUI` component with `appBarItems` prop as

```js
<BaseUI
  onLogout={()=> // logout logic}
  applicationName= "XXXX"
  appBarItems = {[
    <a href={actualUrl} onClick={HomeClick} className="Home" />,
      <div className="AdvanceSearch">
        {searchTextVisible ? (
          <TextField
            fullWidth className="AdvanceSearchTextWidth"
            label=""
            value={searchText}
            onKeyPress={(ev: any) => {
              if (ev.key === "Enter") {                    
                window.location.href = window.location.href.toString().substr(0,window.location.href.indexOf("#") + 1) + "/advancesearch/" + searchText.toString() .split("/").join("_");
                ev.preventDefault();
              }
            }}
            onChange={(v: string) => {
            setSearchText(v);}}
            placeholder="Search here"
          />
        ) : ("")}
      {searchTextVisible ? <Icon name="cross" onClick={HideSearch} /> : ""}
      {!searchTextVisible ? <Icon name="search" onClick={ShowSearch} /> : ""}
    </div>,
    // and some more <div></div> goes here
  ]}
/>
```

Currently I want to refactor the code present in the `appBarItems` into another file/component. I tried adding the code to another component

```
const appBarItems = (): ReactElement<IAppBarItem[]> => {
  return (
    <div>
      <a href={actualUrl} onClick={HomeClick} className="Home" />,
      <div className="AdvanceSearch">
        {searchTextVisible ? (
          <TextField
            fullWidth className="AdvanceSearchTextWidth"
            label=""
            value={searchText}
            onKeyPress={(ev: any) => {
              if (ev.key === "Enter") {
                window.location.href = window.location.href.toString().substr(0, window.location.href.indexOf("#") + 1) +                       "/advancesearch/" + searchText.toString() .split("/").join("_");
                ev.preventDefault();
              }
            }}
          onChange={(v: string) => {
          setSearchText(v);}}
          placeholder="Search here"
        />) : ("")}
        {searchTextVisible ? <Icon name="cross" onClick={HideSearch} /> : ""}
        {!searchTextVisible ? <Icon name="search" onClick={ShowSearch} /> : ""}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

The state variables are declared using the `UseState` and it has few arrow functions.

and try to use it the `BaseUI`

```
<BaseUI
...
appBarItems = AppBarItems// gives error
appBarItems = [AppBarItems]// gives error
</BaseUI>
```

The error is

```
Type '() => ReactElement<IAppBarItem[]>' is 
not assignable to type 'ReactElement<(({ iconName, text, tooltip, 
onClick, className, style, dataAttributes 
}: IAppBarItem) => Element) 
| (({ iconName, href, openInNewTab, 
tooltip, className, style, dataAttributes 
}: IAppBarAnchor) => Element), 
string | JSXElementConstructor<any>> 
[]'.ts(2322)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems your `appBarItems` component only accepts `React.Element` as valid inputs. The new element you created is a function instead:

```
const AppBarItems: React.Element<IAppBarItem> = () => {...};
```

The type assigned to `AppBarItems` is also incorrect as you are creating a function that *returns* the `React.Element` instead of returning the element directly.

The fix would be:

```
const AppBarItems: React.Element<IAppBarItem> = (
  <div>
   ... dont render a list here, build the actual JSX here...
  </div>
);
```

But it seems you are trying to make this a stateful component. You can think of `React.Element` being the actual DOM elements. It's not a React component yet.

To make it a react component, try this:

```js
const AppBarItems: JSXElementConstructor<any>= (_props) => {
  const [state, setState] = useState('');

  return (
    <div>...</div> //dont render a list here, build the actual JSX here
  );
};
```

```js
<BaseUI
  onLogout={() => {}}
  appBarItems={<AppBarItems />}
/>
```

Notice we're rendering a React component now using `<AppBarItem />` and not creating a JS variable whose value is a react element.

I would encourage you to understand the difference between these two syntaxes:

```js
const MyElement = <p>I am a DOM element!</p>;
```

v/s

```js
const MyComponent = () => <p>I am a component!</p>
```

usage:

```js
const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <MyComponent />
      {MyElement}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: I refactored the code based on your answer, but I'm facing another error, so I posted another question for it. Can you look at it? [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75768880/type-reactelementtype-type-is-missing-the-following-properties-from-type-react)