# Type ReactElement<type,type> is missing the following properties from Type ReactElement of Custom Type

Tags: reactjs

I have a `BaseUI` component with `appBarItems` prop as

```js
<BaseUI
  onLogout={()=> // logout logic}
  applicationName= "XXXX"
  appBarItems = {[
    <a href={actualUrl} onClick={HomeClick} className="Home" />,
      <div className="AdvanceSearch">
        {searchTextVisible ? (
          <TextField
            fullWidth className="AdvanceSearchTextWidth"
            label=""
            value={searchText}
            onKeyPress={(ev: any) => {
              if (ev.key === "Enter") {                    
                window.location.href = window.location.href.toString().substr(0,window.location.href.indexOf("#") + 1) + "/advancesearch/" + searchText.toString() .split("/").join("_");
                ev.preventDefault();
              }
            }}
            onChange={(v: string) => {
            setSearchText(v);}}
            placeholder="Search here"
          />
        ) : ("")}
      {searchTextVisible ? <Icon name="cross" onClick={HideSearch} /> : ""}
      {!searchTextVisible ? <Icon name="search" onClick={ShowSearch} /> : ""}
    </div>,
    // and some more <div></div> goes here
  ]}
/>
```

Currently I want to refactor the code present in the `appBarItems` into another file/component. I tried adding the code to another component

```
const AppBarItems: JSXElementConstructor<any>= (_props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <a href={actualUrl} onClick={HomeClick} className="Home" />,
      <div className="AdvanceSearch">
        {searchTextVisible ? (
          <TextField
            fullWidth className="AdvanceSearchTextWidth"
            label=""
            value={searchText}
            onKeyPress={(ev: any) => {
              if (ev.key === "Enter") {
                window.location.href = window.location.href.toString().substr(0, window.location.href.indexOf("#") + 1) +                       "/advancesearch/" + searchText.toString() .split("/").join("_");
                ev.preventDefault();
              }
            }}
          onChange={(v: string) => {
          setSearchText(v);}}
          placeholder="Search here"
        />) : ("")}
        {searchTextVisible ? <Icon name="cross" onClick={HideSearch} /> : ""}
        {!searchTextVisible ? <Icon name="search" onClick={ShowSearch} /> : ""}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

The state variables are declared using the `UseState` and it has few arrow functions.

and try to use it the `BaseUI`

```
<BaseUI
...
appBarItems = {<AppBarItems/>}// gives error   
</BaseUI>
```

The error is

```
Type 'ReactElement<any, any>' is missing 
the following properties from type 
ReactElement<(({ iconName, text, tooltip, 
onClick, className, style, dataAttributes 
}: IAppBarItem) => Element) | (({ iconName, 
href, openInNewTab, tooltip, className, 
style, dataAttributes }: IAppBarAnchor) => 
Element), string | 
JSXElementConstructor<any>>[]': length, 
pop, push, concat, and 29 more.ts(2740)"
```

Comment: It expects an array. You're passing a single element.

Comment: I cannot comprehend how to pass array.

Comment: ... brackets? `[` and `]`?

Comment: If I do this ```const AppBarItems: JSXElementConstructor<any>[]= (_props:any): => {``` it throws error ```Type '(_props: any) => any' is not assignable to type 'JSXElementConstructor<any>[]'.ts(2322)```

Comment: They are supposed to be here => `appBarItems = {[<AppBarItems/>]}`

Comment: @vr.  It worked. Can you post an answer so that it can be useful to others in future?